# Deciding iOS version: pros and cons

Tags: ios

I have following question.

Say I want to start to write an app in one month.

What are the ***advantages*** and ***disadvantages*** if I:

- 1) Write the app such that **only** users of iOS7 can use it.
- 2) Write an app with **iOS6/5** in mind. Meaning app is not optimized for iOS7 (e.g., UI etc.) - however due to forward compatibility I assume iOS7 users can still use it.
- 3) Write an app that is optimized for iOS7 but users of iOS 6 can still use it.

*Example* advantages and disadvantages.

- The disadvantage of supporting only iOS7 maybe that users with other version of iOS can't use it.
- Disadvantage of optimizing app for iOS7 while it is usable also for iOS6 may be a lot of work.

In this fashion, I hope that the users here will help me list advantages and disadvantages of the three items I listed initially.

Comment: Always support as many non-retiring versions as possible. You have to (compulsory) support iOS 7 in near future, so your choice would only be supporting iOS 5 or not.

Comment: "Concrete" has nothing to to with "opinion based". "Opinion based" does not mean its a bad question, no it's a good one. But by the rules of this site it does not belong on Stackoverflow if it is about opinions that people have. I think that what the closers meant.

Comment: @towi: Yes but saying that for example developing something for this iOS has **this** and **that** pros and cons is not an opinion, it can be substituted with facts. For example: developing for iOS4 is not good because it does not have many users. etc.

Comment: You may be right. But you have to agree that your formulation of the question allows for opinions and facts. A good start would be listing the arguments that you have come up so far yorsself, as guiding examples. After a proper re-edit the question will be put in for re-opening. You should abstain then from "this is a joke" throw-ins, too.

Comment: @towi: I have modified it, why is it still closed?

Comment: @rmaddy: can you please look at the question now? I don't think this is opinion based?

Comment: Editing a question doesn't magically reopen it. 5 people now need to vote to reopen the question. That's not likely to happen any time soon, if ever.

Comment: @rmaddy: I modified it now, well if it won't happen, I will post it separately then later.

Comment: @Kurt Revis: please see the modified post, I think it should be reopened.

Comment: @jrturton: please see the modified question, I think it should be reopened now.

Comment: I think it still is awfully close to an opinion based question. But i think you would argue "I ask for facts". No, I don't think so. A "advantage" or "disadvantage" is very often (almost always?) an opinion. I gave you your 1st reopen vote, but to even highen your chances, what do you think of givin a list of things you came up with so far?

Comment: @towi: I have listed some things I came up with myself already, please see there. No advantage/disadvantage is not always an opinion: For example, the disadvantage of living on North Pole is that it is cold there, and it is a fact, and none will argue.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that you already added examples. Good. If iOS6 or iOS7 would be as extreme as the north-pole you were right, but what about iceland? I know people who went there, even if its' cold :-)

Comment: @towi: hm... iceland, never been there should be nice :). Anyway I might need to repost it as one user said it might not get reopened (he said "if ever" it will be reopened- and I can't wait so long). But thanks for your understanding, I appreciate it. If I have better examples of Advantages and Disadvantages which are based on facts, I will let you know :))) just need to go now.

Comment: Actually, I don#t think its a good SO question. Maybe another stackexchange site? Maybe some tottally different forum? Apple must have those.

Comment: @towi: I think I tried on Apple too, with no results - I think I gave it a try on programmers stack exchange too. I just wanted to have a good overview of pros and cons - so that I could choose based on that for which iOS to go

Answer (score 2):

If you're using public, non-deprecated official iOS SDK ( at that time this answer is written, the current stable version is iOS 6.1 ), you can support iOS 5 & 6. The current stable (non-beta) Xcode cannot support iOS 7 development yet.

Also, always support as many non-retiring versions as possible. You have to (compulsory) support iOS 7 in near future, so your choice would only be supporting iOS 5 or not.

Note: Since iOS 5 & iOS 6 are quite similar, supporting iOS 5 won't make you write a lot more codes.

In addition to above :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207126/release-of-ios-7-affecting-development

1. Application must be compatible with both the latest version and second last version.
2. So, once iOS 7 is released fully, make your app compatible with iOS 7 also. It will increase your sales.
3. Your development target has to be iOS 5 when developing the application. There is not much difference in terms of view in iOS 5 and iOS 6, but some features may not be available because of Frameworks advancement. So, take care of that.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi Shivan, so can we say one option is: I write an application now for iOS6 and iOS5 --- and later after some time I may need to "upgrade" it to support iOS7 too right? (I thought supporting both iOS6 and iOS7 might be a lot of work, what information do you have about it?).

Comment: Yes, as long as you're not using deprecating functions, your apps will be safe to migrate to iOS 7.

Comment: So, again to sum up: You recommend now I target iOS5 and iOS6 --- and after some time, think how to redesign it so that it supports iOS7 also??

Comment: No need to redesign. It will **automatically** support iOS 7. I'm using iOS 7 beta, almost all apps are running smoothly.

Comment: Shivan, can you give me some info on this? I am beginner in this area. So, you say, if I have app for iOS 5 for example, does it mean that it will run also on **future** iOS versions? (e.g., iOS6, iOS7?)

Comment: Yes, Apps targeting iOS 5 can still be running on iOS 7. Even apps targeting iOS 4 is okay to run on iOS 7 too.

Comment: >> "Yes, Apps targeting iOS 5 can still be running on iOS 7. Even apps targeting iOS 4 is okay to run on iOS 7". 

Shivan, can you give me a link which has more information about this?

Comment: I have ~10 apps in App Store targeting iOS 5 and they are running fine on iOS 7.

Comment: I understand. But why do sites like this exist then: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/ (especially  the part about retina displays for example)? Also, I heard supporting iOS6 and iOS7 maybe a lot of work by other programmers - why do they support other versions too, if once an application is written for iOS5, it can run on all future iOS versions too?

Comment: Try first, ask later. To support retina display, you just have to prepare another set of graphical assets.

Comment: Shivan, what do you mean with: "You have to (compulsory) support iOS 7 in near future" -- what do you mean with **support** here? what do you assume there?

Comment: To support iOS 7, you must check you have not used iOS 7 deprecated functions.

Comment: so you say one of my option is to write the app for iOS5 and iOS6 users? even though it may not look nice on iOS7 it will still run on iOS7?